# Doctrine ODM Query IS NULL

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-odm, odm

Is it possible to use `IS NULL` in Doctrine ODM Query? Only thing i found is `fieldIsset()`, which generates `IS NOT NULL`, but i cannot negate it. I've tired

`$queryBuilder
    ->andWhere()
    ->not()
    ->fieldIsset('fieldSelector');`

but, resulting query is `(NOT document.[fieldSelector] IS NOT NULL)`. Did anyone ran into similar problem?

Answer (score 2):

try like this:

```
$queryBuilder
    ->where('fieldSelector IS NULL')
;
```

Cheers

**EDIT**:

Sorry, did not see you use ODM...

So, maybe by this way:

```
$queryBuilder   
    ->field('fieldSelector')->equals(null)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to more conditions you can use javascript in where function

```
$queryBuilder
->where("function() { return (typeof(this.fieldSelector) =='undefined'); }")
```

this is reference 
[link](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/1.2.x/reference/query-builder-api.html)

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
$queryBuilder
   ->eq($queryBuilder->ifNull('$field', null), null)
;
```

To count it:

```
$queryBuilder
   ->project()
   ->field('count')
     ->cond(
         $queryBuilder->eq($queryBuilder->ifNull('$field', null), null),
         0,
         1
       )
->group()
   ->field('id')
   ->expression(null)
   ->field('count')
   ->expression($queryBuilder->sum('$count'))
```